# Rearranging + resizing partitions on Ubuntu + Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Background: I had Windows 10 on my laptop, then dual booted Ubuntu alongside it. I have a 256GB SSD and allocated Ubuntu 40(38.56) GB

I am in a frustrating position now, where my Windows and Ubuntu partitions are in an unfortunate ordering - I have plenty of free space in my Windows partition but I cannot migrate this to my Ubuntu partition because the Windows partition is "before" my Ubuntu one.

GParted:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJsei.png)

Is there any way to resize my Ubuntu partition without losing data? I have seen multiple questions related to this, but all of them have the Ubuntu partition before the Windows one, which makes things easier.

Ideally I would not like to lose Windows data either, but I have a backup so as long as it is still bootable that would still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a risk when you resize partitions, but since you have a backup I wouldn't worry too much. I, too, have my Windows data before my Linux data, so that's not an issue.

Here's what you need to do:

- Shrink the Windows data partition
- Delete the swap partition
- Grow the Ubuntu data partition (make sure you leave space for swap)
- Create a new swap partition

Before you reboot, check the UUID/device name of the new swap partition and adjust your `/etc/fstab` accordingly.

Comment: You show bitlocker. Be sure to only resize NTFS using Windows tools & reboot immediately to let Windows run chkdsk which is required after any resize. Also Windows NTFS needs 30% free to work well. At 10% free, you barely have room to run a defrag.

Comment: You haven’t mentioned which version of Ubuntu that you are running. I don’t remember exactly when but certainly by 18.04 it has used a swap file rather than a swap partition. You might want to change to a swap file before doing anything else. It’s easy to find how to do that

Comment: The steps in the answer worked like a charm! @PonJar - this is 18.04, is there any advantage to creating a swap file over a partition? I ended up going with a partition, but I could redo that if there are significant benefits

Comment: As I understand it using a swap file simplifies the partitioning scheme making the kind of operation you have just done somewhat easier. It is also easier to change the size of the file should you ever need to. Given where you are now with your installation there is probably no real benefit in changing. If you ever do a fresh install without manual partitioning you will end up with a swap file.